# Symfony LTS: how to upgrade from 3.4 to 4.4?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-4.4

Tell me please, what steps are required in order to upgrade Symfony from 3.4 to 4.4 LTS?

Comment: first upgrade to 4.0, then to 4.4: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-upgrade there are some minor changes. however your question is not fit for SO.

Answer (score 7):

You can visit [the official Symfony GitHub repository](https://github.com/symfony/symfony) and switch to the 4.4 branch (or access said branch directly via this [url](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/4.4)). Inside that repository you will find a series of files with specific instructions on how to upgrade:

[UPGRADE-4.0.md](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/UPGRADE-4.0.md) - UPGRADE FROM 3.x to 4.0

[UPGRADE-4.1.md](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/UPGRADE-4.1.md) - UPGRADE FROM 4.0 to 4.1

[UPGRADE-4.2.md](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/UPGRADE-4.2.md) - UPGRADE FROM 4.1 to 4.2

[UPGRADE-4.3.md](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/UPGRADE-4.3.md) - UPGRADE FROM 4.2 to 4.3

[UPGRADE-4.4.md](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/UPGRADE-4.4.md) - UPGRADE FROM 4.3 to 4.4

Hope this helps.